# Output PHP Variable Value In A Position On The Page That Is In A Different Scope?

Tags: php, loops, scope, counter

I have a page design where a posts grid is in the second section of the page. There is a simple counter stored by reference in the `$count_images` variable.

On the page design, the loop that outputs the posts is below where the count total is going to be displayed (a simplified example given below).

Is there a way of outputting this higher up the page after the $count_images++ has been implemented?

I know I can solve this with Javascript by placing the counter value in a hidden element after the while loop and then swapping out the innerText of the `<p>` tag at the top of the page, but wondered if there was a (preferred) way around this problem in PHP?

I really apologise if there is a screamingly obvious answer to this, but I'm still relatively new to coding in general and PHP and I can't seem to find any similar examples / questions.

```
<p id="counter">Number of images by this contributor: <?php // $count_images to be echoed near top of page ?></p>

<?php
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM imageposts WHERE username = :username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();   

    $count_images = 0;  // AT THE BEGINNING THERE ARE 0 IMAGES

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {   // LOOP START

        $db_image_id = htmlspecialchars($row['image_id']);
        $db_image_title = htmlspecialchars($row['image_title']);
        $db_image_tags = htmlspecialchars($row['image_tags']);
        $db_image_filename = htmlspecialchars($row['filename']);

        if ($db_image_filename != NULL  && $db_image_filename != '') {
            $count_images++;  // IF IMAGE FOUND, INCREASE BY +1
        }

?>
<figure>

<!-- html is outputted here including values using the PHP variables above -->

</figure>
<?php } // END OF WHILE LOOP ?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with just running your loop further up the page?

Comment: That's the issue with saving loops ... you start with a quick solve and find out that something needs to be finished before you can display it... :) you can display this at the very end after your loop. Or add a few JavaScript lines and display $count_images after the page loads or update it.

Comment: @NotMe - the client wants the posts below the count. Unless there's a way of running the loop further up and outputting it lower down? I can't work out how to do that though?

Comment: In php you cannot do this, the only way is to grab the variables to an array or arrays display the count and then run the loop from the grabbed array(s)... you can't do JS stuff with php - this count is counted within the loop. You either display data on the fetch loop fly or grab it and display it in another loop.

Comment: @paulo_cam: Save the output of the loop to a string.  emit it where you want.